What is the use case of VIEW in SQL?
I know how to create and use view but struggling with it's use case, in real projects where do sql view fits?
**Create a view: **
CREATE VIEW [Products Above Average Price] AS
SELECT ProductName, Price
FROM Products
WHERE Price > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products);

**use a view: **
SELECT * FROM [Products Above Average Price];


It's like writing a function in a programming language, it allows you to avoid having to write the same thing over and over.

BTW, MySQL doesn't use square brackets, it uses backticks. Square brackets are SQL-Server syntax.
